# While MouseDown, first slowly decrease number, then increase decreasing speed (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, timer, mousedown

As the title suggests I'm stuck with a MouseDown problem. 
What I want in "pseudocode"

```
While ("#arrowUp").mouseDown(function() {
    counter++; //One time directly when pressed
    if(MouseDownTime > 500){ //500ms that is
       setTimeOut({counter++}, 75);  //Meaning, every 75ms counter++
    }
```

}

I have been looking around at Stack Overflow for over two days now. And I succeeded to increment every 75ms, but then I couldn't build in the `if(MouseDownTime > 500)`-statement, while still being able to increase the counter every 75ms after the 500ms.

```
$("#tempUp").mousedown(function() {     //When longer pressed, automatically faster increase Temperature
    int = setInterval(editTemp(currTemp+1), 250);
    })
                .mouseup(function() {
    clearInterval(int);
    numberOfRepeats = 0;        
    });
```

This is code I have of of my function so far. Could anyone help me out? Or am I asking the question in a wrong way? (non-constructive)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you can make use of a combination of `setTimeout` and `setInterval`, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{
    var temp = 0;
    var to   = null;
    var iv   = null;

    $("#ClickMe").on("mousedown", function () 
    {
        temp++;
        $("#Temp").html(temp);
        to = setTimeout(function () 
        {
            iv = setInterval(function () 
            {
                temp++;
                $("#Temp").html(temp);
            }, 75);
        }, 500);
    }).on("mouseup mouseleave", function () 
    {
        clearTimeout(to);
        clearInterval(iv);
    });
});
```

See this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/r4eWs/136/)** for an example.

EDIT: Added the `mouseleave` event as well as suggested by José F. Romaniello.

Comment: Thanks alot! It makes my site alot better! Strange though that I couldn't find this anywhere. Seems to me that alot of people use this.

Comment: Glad I could help! It seems indeed like it's something lots of people use, but it's kinda hard to describe the problem with one or few words. Maybe that's the reason it's hard to find anything about the matter.

Comment: I know this is very old but you might consider doing handling the "mouseleave" event the same way than mouseup.

Comment: @JoséF.Romaniello Thanks for the suggestion! It indeed makes sense including the `mouseleave` event as well.